# method for passing java variable value to jstl in jsp page

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl, el

I found out the code to pass a java variable to jstl like this :-

```
<%
String str = "abc";
pageContext.setAttribute("str", str);
%>
```

and to get that value in jstl tags we will have to use the code like this :-

```
<c:out value="${str}"/>
```

My main question is that, if there any other method to do so to pass on the values, from java to jstl?

Answer (score 2):

it looks for pageContext, request attributes, session attributes, application context for variable resolution, so you can put the value in any of this

in this example you are putting it in `pageContext`

From our [**EL wiki**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

```
${str}
```

does basically the same as the following in "raw" scriptlet code (the below example is for simplicity, in reality the reflection API is used to obtain the methods and invoke them):

where [`PageContext#findAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#findAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) scans the attributes of respectively the `PageContext` (page scope), `HttpServletRequest` (request scope), `HttpSession` (session scope) and `ServletContext` (application scope) **until the first non-null value is found**. Please note that it thus doesn't print "null" when the value is null nor throws a `NullPointerException` unlike as when using scriptlets. In other words, EL is *null-safe*.

Comment: yes in the same page only, so the pagecontext. Just want to confirm if there is some alternative?

Comment: Alternative is to pass it as url (for example : someurl.com?key=value parameter and access it as ${param.key})

Comment: okay thankyou so much but if there some more alternative because I don't want to pass the variable into url..

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing values to JSTL , you are setting scoped attributes . You can set attributes to `request`,`session` and `context` or you can pass `request` parameters to the JSP.

Comment: Yes I am setting scope attributes, but please help me if there is some other way to execute the similar logic

Comment: Pass request parameters as , Jigar Joshi mentioned in his comments.